# What is the closed form representation of the sum of the first $\text{int}(n/2)$ terms of binomial expansion $(f+(1-f))^n$?

Tags: self-learning, binomial-theorem

Say that we have this polynomial $(f + (1-f))^n$ where $f$ and $n$ are some positive real numbers, except that $f$ is a constant, but $n$ is a variable.

That term can be expanded using the binomial theorem:
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
   (f+(1-f))^n &= \sum_{i = 1}^n {n \choose i} f^i (1-f)^{n-i}\\
&= 1
\end{split}\end{equation}

I want to find the sum the *upper* half terms of the full expansion, namely:

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{i = \text{int}(n/2)+1}^n {n \choose i} f^i (1-f)^{n-i}
\end{equation}

I don't want the sum of the first half terms, namely:

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{i = 1}^{\text{int}(n/2)} {n \choose i} f^i (1-f)^{n-i}
\end{equation}

But we can use the lower part that I don't want to rephrase the upper part that I want as follows:
\begin{equation}
  1-\sum_{i = 1}^{\text{int}(n/2)} {n \choose i} f^i (1-f)^{n-i}
\end{equation}

More specifically, I wish to have a function $g(n)$ that, for any $n$, it spits out a number that is the sum of the upper half parts.

My struggle so far is in finding a close-form solution. I can't go algebra with this weird looking sum.

### My attempt

Use this equation:
\begin{equation}
  \Big(\sum_{i = \text{int}(n/2)+1}^n {n \choose i} f^i (1-f)^{n-i}\Big)+ \Big(\sum_{i = 1}^{\text{int}(n/2)} {n \choose i} f^i (1-f)^{n-i}\Big) = 1
\end{equation}

And rephrase it so that we end up having only $n$ on one side alone, and no $n$s on the other side.

And I am stuck here. Is this even approachable?

Answer (score 1):

You can express it using hypergeometric functions.  If $n = 2m$ is even, it is (according to Maple)

$$ {2\,m\choose m+1}{f}^{m+1} \left( 1-f \right) ^{m-1}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,-m+1;\,m+2;\,{\frac {f}{-1+f}})}
$$

while if $n=2m+1$ is odd,

$${2m+2 \choose m+1} \dfrac{{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,2\,m+2;\,m+2;\,f)}{f}^{m+1} \left( 1-f
 \right) ^{m+1}}{2}
$$

Comment: Is there any easier perspective to all this? I am new to all this. Maple seems like a name that I did hear previously, but I certainly never used it. I also have no idea what $F_1$ is, nor that I know what hypergeometric functions are. Sorry for being this stupid. If you can save me somehow I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: The short answer is: it likely does not have a closed-form expression in terms of functions you have heard of.  This can also be stated as the probability of getting more than $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ heads in $n$ flips of a biased coin with probability $f$ of heads on each flip, so it is certainly something that is well-studied.

Comment: By representing the problem by using $_2F_1$, are we any closer to find the smallest value of $n$ that leads to an answer of $10^{-15}$? This is my primary reason in trying to represent that as a function of $n$ (because it allows me to solve $\sum_{i = 1}^{\text{int}(n/2)} {n \choose i} f^i (1-f)^{n-i} \le 10^{-15}$ for $n$.

Comment: @caveman Well, if you use a CAS that knows how to evaluate hypergeometric functions, it does make it somewhat easier to evaluate the sum for given $n$ and $f$.  But it would be more productive to investigate the asymptotics of your sum, rather than trying for an exact expression.  Again, this is well-studied (look up Large Deviations).

Comment: Asymptotically, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} stuff = 0$. Is this what you mean? I wonder how does knowing this information helps.

Comment: Better asymptotics than that are available:  see the [Cramér-Chernoff theorem](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~srikant/ECE567/Fall09/cramer-many-sources.pdf).