# What are hypergeometric functions in layman terms?

Tags: self-learning, hypergeometric-function

Could someone please explain what are these in layman terms? Someone [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1734071/307745) told me that and I still can't figure out what they mean on my own after giving Google a number of hits.

Wikipedia says this:
$$
_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{(c)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!}
$$

What does $(?)_n$ notation mean?

I also fail to see why all this makes any sense. I think I need some layman introduction in very simple terms.

Comment: The notation is explained literally in the next line after this definition in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

Comment: @YuriyS thanks. Looks to me like a kind of generalization of the factorial. Agree?

Comment: see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html)

Comment: Maybe the first 2 or 3 pages of [these notes](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/hyper.pdf) will help. My vague understanding of them is that when you apply the ratio test to determine the interval of convergence (like you do in a 2nd semester calculus course), before taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ you get a rational function of $n.$ Or something like that. Alternatively, the term $a_{n+1}x^{n+1}$ in the power series expansion is such that $a_{n+1}=R(n)a_{n}$ for some rational function $R(n).$ (The rational function $R$ doesn't vary when $n$ varies.)

Comment: To elaborate a little - hypergeometric functions are a very useful generalization of commonly used (elementary and special) functions. Because of that, we can write solutions to many problems in general form, using these functions (differential equations, infinite series, integrals, etc). Then it's possible that there is a way to transform the solution to another, easier function. If not, computing hypergeometric functions is still easier, than just numerically solving the problem every time